# Printing something on the basis of a condition in a column of a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a df as below and need to print a string on the basis of the condition as follows:

```
       Name Age     University  City
0      Ankit    23          BHU     Pune
1     Aishwarya 21          BHU     Pune
2     Shaurya   22          BHU     Pune
3     Shivangi  21          BHU     Pune

for i in df:
    if df['Age']=='BHU'and df['City']=='Pune':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('error')
```

gives `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are comparing University and City name. If University is "BHU" and city is "Pune" then you want to print("correct") otherwise you want to print error. If my thought is right then you should follow this code below.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "University"] == "BHU" and df.loc[i, "City"] == "Pune":
        print("correct")
        break
    else:
        print("error")
```

Comment: this gives me 'correct' multiple times - for n records - what if I want 'correct' only to be printed once for n records in a columns

Comment: If you want one 'correct' for n records and skip other data which are also satisfy the condition then you can use "break" after print("correct") in your code. I have edited the code.  Please check this.

Answer (score 1):

You can looping by array created in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
arr = np.where((df['Age']=='BHU') & (df['City']=='Pune'), 'correct', 'error')

for val in arr:
     print(val)
```

Your solution is possible use:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if (row['Age']=='BHU') and (row['City']=='Pune'):
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('error')
```